# How can I define or add the default record to account Receivable or account Payable for Partners odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8, openerp-8

I can't Create a customer because it's required account payable and receivable.
How can i define default Accounts Receivable and Accounts Payable values when creating a partner? These fields are required during partner creation. I would like their Accounts Receivable and Accounts Payable fields to be set by default.
I think that I modify the account type view 411/Client and 401/Supliers type view 
I activate in mode developer
I see a selection box on the top of each form (above the edit/create buttons). An entry of this selection box is 'Set Defaults'.but I didn't see the record by default account Receivable or account Payable,

Please How can I define or add the default record to account Receivable or account Payable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set Accounts Receivable and Accounts Payable with default value you can configure this using the Company Properties option.

You can follow the below-mentioned steps

1. Activate Developer Mode.
2. Go to Settings -> Technical / Parameters -> Company Properties.
3. Create a new Record Account Payable with following values
   [Account Payable Record description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjXzZ.png)
4. Create a new Record Account Receivable with following values
   [Account Receivable Record description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15PUw.png)
5. Keep Resource file blank, so that it will be applicable to all res.partner records.
6. If multi-company is enabled you can select company while creating records in Company Properties.